# $2n-$polygon with pairs of sides identified is compact

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

This is the first problem of Massey's Algebraic Topology.

Show any $2n-$polygon with pairs of sides identified is compact.

I think I want to do induction. However I am stucked at a general case.

Q: If there is a pair of identified edges next to each other, I can cut a triangle and rest out. Then apply induction hypothesis. However how do I prove the statement when the pair of identified edges are not next to each other?

Hint will be sufficient. I think I need to try to cut in a special way.

Comment: Do you know the theorem about continuous images of compact sets?

Comment: @LeeMosher That was dumb of me as I thought I am supposed to do induction. Thanks.